# How to get speed value of a tacx flux S2 with javascript and bluetooth?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth

**Reading speed of a TACX FLUX S 2 with javascript on  chrome navigator **

Hello,
I try to connect to my Tacx Flux S 2 with bluetooth using  this javascript code :

```
function speed() { 
    // UUID of Tacx Flux 2 service
    const SERVICE_UUID = '6e40fec1-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e';

//  speed UUID 
    const CHARACTERISTIC_DATA_UUID = '6e40fec3-b5a3-f393-e0a9-e50e24dcca9e';

// Connect to Tacx Flux 2 device
    navigator.bluetooth.requestDevice({ filters: [{ namePrefix: 'Tacx Flux-2' }] })
        .then(device => {
            console.log('Tacx Flux 2 device found :', device.name);

            return device.gatt.connect();
        })
        .then(server => {
            console.log('Connected to GATT server of device');

            // get  Tacx Flux 2 service
            return server.getPrimaryService(SERVICE_UUID);
        })
        .then(service => {
            console.log(' Tacx Flux 2 service found);

            // get speed characteristic
            return service.getCharacteristic(CHARACTERISTIC_DATA_UUID);
        })
        .then(dataCharacteristic => {
            console.log('speed characteristic found');

            //  périodicly read speed value
            setInterval(() => {
                     dataCharacteristic.readValue()
                    .then(value => {
                        const speed = value.getUint8(0);

                        console.log('speed :', speed);
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        console.error('erreur :',error);
                    });

            }, 1000); // read speed every second
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error :', error);
        });

}
```

It find my tacx device and tells "speed characteristic found" but then it throws an error ("operation not permitted"). So it must come from the readValue operation. I wonder if the UUIDs i use are the correct ones.

I tried to find UUIDS of speed services and characteristic data for my tacx flux S 2 , but i failed.